# Django app running on Apache serves blank 200 responses

Tags: apache2, ubuntu, django

I'm trying to deploy an application built on Django on a Ubuntu 10 Server with mod_wsgi and Apache.
When I try to access certain views, I get a 200 response with no content from the server. These are the views that work and dont work:

```
def this_works(request):
    return render_to_response('admin/index.html')

def this_also_works(request):
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string('admin/index.html'))

def this_doesnt_work(request):
    return SimpleTemplateResponse(Template('Example text'))
```

Besides this, the admin site and the login view don't work either.
The application works perfectly with Django's runserver.

I´d greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: If you haven't already, try swapping `this_doesnt_work()` and `this_works()`.  I suspect the problem might be with your apache or wsgi config and not your Django code, so if you swap the contents of the functions and hit the function that's supposed to be working, you can narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/#using-templateresponse-and-simpletemplateresponse)

It seems that you're using SimpleTemplateResponse wrong.

```
return SimpleTemplateResponse(request, 'admin/index.html')
```

Would be the way to use it the way I see. If you want to render string you would render it your view and just return it using HttpResponse.